# gdb: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug a core file, but when I try to pass it to gdb I get the following output:

```
(gdb) core corecore
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New Thread 57767]
[New Thread 57771]
[New Thread 57772]
[New Thread 57773]
[New Thread 57774]
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
..... //etc.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libfreebl3.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
Warning: couldn't activate thread debugging using libthread_db: Cannot find new threads: generic error
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libfreebl3.so
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Core was generated by `httpclient/vmacore-httpclient-test httpclient/envConfig.xml'.
```

I don't quite understand what is going wrong, because the threads are enumerated correctly and the executable I'm running it for is the same as the executable that dumped it (the same that gdb says generated it)

Comment: The first warning, why is it saying that? is your debugging environment the same as the executing environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840621/gdb-cannot-find-new-threads-generic-error-after-system-update

Comment: @nrathaus It is, I am not really sure why it is saying that, it may have to do something with the fact that I'm generating the core with google's breakpad.

Comment: the link I gave you any good?

Comment: @nrathaus I will check it out

Comment: @nrathaus It may be a mismatch between libthread_db and my pthread library, although I don't know why that would be the case.